# How to upload file by using AWS S3 service in iOS?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

How to upload file by using AWS S3 service in iOS ,
I want to upload selected file to AWS S3 bucket.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code help u to solve your problem

Here is a sample code to upload image on S3 server

Step 1
- initialize AWS S3 configuration with S3 Key and S3 secret key

```
AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSStaticCredentialsProvider alloc]initWithAccessKey:S3_KEY secretKey:S3_SECRET];
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
```

Step 2: 
- upload file /image

```
if ([localReachability isReachable]) {

AWSS3TransferUtility *transferUtility = [AWSS3TransferUtility defaultS3TransferUtility];

AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock completionHandler = ^(AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask *task, NSError *error) {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    MLog(@"Image Upload Completion handler ");
    if (!error) {
      MLog(@"Image is uploaded successfully ");
      [self imageUploadDidFinish];
    }
    else {
      MLog(@"Image is failed to upload");
      MLog(@"Error ::: %@",error);
      [self imageUploadDidFail];
    }
  });
};

[[transferUtility uploadData:fileToUpload bucket:S3_BUCKET key:uploadPath contentType:@"image/jpg" expression:nil completionHander:completionHandler] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {

  if (task.error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
    AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask *uploadTask = task.result;
    [uploadTask  cancel];
  }

  if (task.result) {
    AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask *uploadTask = task.result;
    MLog(@"uploadTask result :: %@",uploadTask);
  }
  return nil;
}];}
```

**API Reference :** 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html